# Offset html anchor with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a really nice pen at https://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/KFkaf (it appears the original is at https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/) that has a fixed menu footer and CSS3 animations to switch between sections. However, the items indeed are fixed, which cause the layout to break when there is more text than available space.

So a thought occurred that I could try modernize this. Add `flex`, or perhaps to make it responsive and mobile first. It would be nice *before-and-after* experience as opposed to more synthetic things I've been learning about CSS. Also I would learn a bit about CSS3 too. The current attempt is at https://codepen.io/veksi/pen/jegdXw (I have removed some legacy stuff and added some items) and also inserted into this post.

Now there is a specific sticking point – or likely many, depending on how deep one wants to go.

**The Problem**

The main problem is that I would like to set up a full page scrolling so that one can scroll from top to bottom, but also back up after choosing one of the subsections. Currently after choosing one of the subsections one can scroll back only on that anchor position, not the top of the page. It seem to be I have a gap in knowledge to solve this particular problem. I have noticed there are problems that are written like *offsetting an anchor*, but I don't know what I don't know how to apply them in this particular situation.

The HTML is fairly short, here it is

```css
 html,body {    
}
body {
   font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;   
   
  /* If this rule is active, one gets a scroll bar.
  Problem: Scrolling upwards to Section 1 does not work after clicking
 any of the subsections.
  */
  /* overflow: auto; */
}

main {
  width: 100%;  
}

section {
scroll-snap-align: start;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border-top: 0.125rem black solid;
font-size: 2.25rem;
     
transform: translateZ(0);    
transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

section p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
width: 100%;
padding-top: 0.5em;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
width: inherit; 
margin: 0; 
}

ul li:nth-child(3n + 1), #main .panel:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 180);  
}

ul li:nth-child(3n + 2), #main .panel:nth-child(3n + 2) {
background: rgb(255, 65, 180);
}

ul li:nth-child(3n + 3), #main .panel:nth-child(3n + 3) {
  background: rgb(0, 180, 255);  
}

ul li {
display: inline-block; 
margin: 0 8px;
margin: 0 0.5em;
padding: 0.3125em 0.5em;
padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
border-radius: 0.125em; 
line-height: 1.5em;
}

ul li a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

.panel h1 {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 4em;
font-size: 4em;
color: #fff;
position:relative;
line-height: 12.5em;
top: 33%;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
}

footer {
position: fixed;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;    
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #333333;
color: #212121;    
}

div[id="section-1"]:target ~ main article section.panel {    
transform: translateY(0vh);
}

div[id= "section-2"]:target ~ main article section.panel {    
transform: translateY(-100%);
}
div[id= "section-3"]:target ~ main article section.panel {    
transform: translateY(-200%);
}

div[id= "section-4"]:target ~ main article section.panel {
  transform: translateY(-300%);
}

div[id= "section-5"]:target ~ main article section.panel {
transform: translateY(-400%);
}

/* This creates the trianble seen on the top. It's a square rotated and the
   color of it is the same as the alternating background color to hide the
   other side.

   Problem: Have approximately the same effect without fixing the location.
*/
.st-deco {
width: 12.5em;
height: 12.5em;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -6.25em;
background: #fa96b5;
transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

/* Problem: The following is fairly complex structure. How to simplify? */
[data-icon]:after {
content: attr(data-icon);    
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(151,24,64,0.2);
position: absolute;
width: 12.5em;
height: 12.5em;
line-height: 12.5em;
text-align: center;
font-size: 5.625em;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -6.25em 0 0 -6.25em;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
}

.st-color, .st-deco {
background: #fa96b5;
}
.st-color [data-icon]:after {
color: #fa96b5;
}
.st-color .st-deco {
background: #fff;
}
.st-color h2 {
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.st-color p {
color: #fff;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

[data-icon]:after {
content: attr(data-icon);    
color: #ccc;    
position: absolute;
width: 12.5em;
height: 12.5em;
line-height: 12.5em;
text-align: center;
font-size: 5.625rem;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -6.25em 0 0 -6.25em;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(25%);
}

.st-deco {
width: 7.5em;
height: 7.5em;
margin-left: -3.75em;
}
[data-icon]:after {
font-size: 3.75rem;
transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(15%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="section-1"></div>
    <div id="section-2"></div>
    <div id="section-3"></div>
    <div id="section-4"></div>
    <div id="section-5"></div>
<main>
    <article>
      <section class="panel st-color" id="st-panel-1">
        <div class="st-deco" data-icon="*"></div>
        <p>Section One</p></section>
      <section class="panel" id="st-panel-2">
        <div class="st-deco" data-icon="*"></div>
        <p>Section Two</p></section>
      <section class="panel st-color" id="st-panel-3">
        <div class="st-deco" data-icon="*"></div>
        <p>Section Three</p>
        <p>1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <p>2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <p>3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <p>4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        <p>5: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
      </section>
      <section class="panel" id="st-panel-4">
        <div class="st-deco" data-icon="*"></div>
        <p>Section Four</p>        
      </section>
      <section class="panel st-color" id="st-panel-5">
        <div class="st-deco" data-icon="*"></div>
        <p>Section Five</p>        
      </section>
 </article>
</main>
   <footer>              
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#section-5">Section 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>  
  </body>
</html>
```

(The snippet doesn't show correctly in the small window.)

A secondary problem is that the contents going on top of the section header. I mention this since they're partially related to this scrolling issue as noted in the CSS comments that I can get a scrollbar and scroll, albeit coming up with this anchor issue. These can be solved by moving the contents a bit, but I suppose it is a separate question. I'm hoping to learn something about pseudo-selectors to make it better.

(As an aside, if one could dynamically calculate the transformtion offset, it would be possible to do the smooth scrolling on arbitrary length contents. As in "scroll into this anchor position").